# Django REST Framework: Response is not defined error

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to connect to Twitter API (tweepy) but it does not seem to work

my views.py

```
class TwitterAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        consumer_key = 'XXX'
        consumer_secret = 'XXX'
        access_token = 'XXX'
        access_token_secret = 'XXX'

        auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
        
        return Response('OK')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "auth/twitter/redirect/",
         views.TwitterAPI.as_view(),
    )
]
```

When I try tto access the url it throws an error
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: name 'Response' is not defined

When I tried to change the class, not tu use get, it also throws an error like GET is not allowed

Sorry I really can't get how to connect to the twitter api in rest framwork

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error occurs because `Response` is not defined. Fix the error by import `Response` first. Define the snippet below at the top of your class `TwitterAPI`

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Importing the response function

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```